# Converting video into bitmap

Tags: android-studio, bitmap

sorry if this question looks weird. I want to know if it is possible to convert a video file into bitmap in android studio. I have a video saved in the external storage of my device. I want to upload the video to a web server but I want the video to first be converted to bitmap.

Comment: you want the phone to turn each frame to bitmap ? and what does it do with it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a Cloud service to convert video into bitmap files since you already uploading the video to web anyway